# Fade some part of google maps in android v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am expecting that the circle part should be highlighted and remaining part of `map` should be fade out.

I googled it but found `fade out marker` but not for some area.

Please suggest me how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a circle highlighted in the center of the screen , you can try overlaying a framelayout over the Map fragment. Additionally you can add a 'Circle' object on GoogleMap object with a radius around a latlng and fill it with a color. You can look at Google Maps API for How to add a circle on a google map.